# How to select all values from json file in VS CODE?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I've trying to found a way to select all json values in vscode like this:

```
{
  "HOME": {
     "DETAIL1": "VALUE1",
     "DETAIL2": "VALUE2",
     "DETAIL3": "VALUE3",
     "DETAIL4": "VALUE4",
   },
  "ASSET": {
     "DETAIL1": "VALUE1",
     "DETAIL2": "VALUE2",
     "DETAIL3": "VALUE3",
     "DETAIL4": "VALUE4",
   }
}
```

I'd like to select all values that are strings types, not object types. Is it possible? has anyone done this?

Tanks to advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- select `: "`
- select All : Ctrl+Shift+L
- Cursor/Arrow-Right
- Select Till End: Shift+End
- Reduce selection: Cursor/Arrow-Left Cursor/Arrow-Left